# Insert data-bound HTML into standalone auto-binding template

Tags: polymer

It is [documented](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#boundhtml) that you can override Polymer's data binding default behavior of escaping HTML by using the injectBoundHTML method.

That's fine for some use cases, but is there a way to prevent HTML escaping for just standalone templates?

For example, I have a template in the `<body>` of my HTML page that looks like this; how can I prevent the HTML of the *myHTMLsnippet* value from being escaped?

```
<template is="auto-binding">
   <div>{{myHTMLsnippet}}</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround by nesting the [juicy-html](https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-html) element inside the auto-binding template.

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <div>
    <template is="juicy-html" content="{{myHTMLsnippet}}"></template>
  </div>
</template>
```